# How to create complex javascript objects

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to create a javascript object to send as a parameter.

I need to send it in this format:

```
params (Object) (defaults to: {}) —
    Bucket — required — (String)
    Delete — required — (map)
        Objects — required — (Array<map>)
            Key — required — (String) Key name of the object to delete.
```

How can I construct this object and fill it out?

I'm doing this:

```
var params = {
    Bucket : data.bucket,
    Delete: [{
    Objects:[{ Key:""}] }]  
};

for(i=0;i<data.keys.length;i++){
    params.Delete[0].Objects.push({Key: data.keys[i]})
}
```

And I get an error message from the library saying that my object is missing the key `Objects` inside of `Delete`

When I `console.log` `params` I get

```
{ Bucket: 'ct.presentations',
Delete: [ { Objects: [Object] } ] }
```

What's the best way for creating objects like this?

---

As Alex pointed out below, `map` in Javascript, isn't a type of array like I thought it was, so instead of

`Delete:[{`
I should have done
`Delete:{`

Comment: try params.Delete[0].push({Key: data.keys[i]}

Comment: @Dan that gave me `Object #<Object> has no method 'push'`

Comment: Wow is that indentation hard to read. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've made `Delete` an array *containing* an object that has `Objects` as a key. Sounds like it shouldn't be an array:

```
var params = {
        Bucket : data.bucket,
        Delete: {
            Objects: []
        }
    };

    for(i=0;i<data.keys.length;i++){
        params.Delete.Objects.push({Key: data.keys[i]})
    }
```

Also note that I removed the `{Key: ""}` from inside the `[]` in `Objects` (on the fourth line). If you really meant to have an object with an empty key as the first entry in the array, add that back, but I suspect you didn't.

Comment: `map` in other languages typically translates to a plain object `{}` in `JavaScript`. So this sounds right to me.

Comment: @AlexWayne Oh. That explains it. I thought map was a type of list.

Comment: That worked, except the `Delete[0]` should be changed to `Delete` seeing as it is no longer an array. It gave me errors the other way around

Comment: @Houseman It's called a `map` because it "maps" keys to values. Other names are "hash" or "dictionary". Most languages have a construct for this, and in JavaScript that construct is "object".